# Palm Desktop for Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, data-synchronization

I've got a Palm Centro and would like to sync all its content to Palm Desktop or similar programme. Is there any enthusiasts site or any software which can help with that?

(It is ridiculous that these days there is no good analogue to Palm Desktop on any platform).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last ever version of Palm Desktop for Mac [4.2.2] was released in 2008 - though 4.2.1 is more common, & still available if you look around - https://palm-desktop.en.softonic.com/palm though I haven't run the Mac version in a long time, so compatibility might be suspect.

I've found it's simpler to use a VM of Windows 7 & install to that - though my Palm iQue 360 installer now fails on anything other than a backup restored drive, as the associated internet app downloader points to nowhere.

It's not hugely surprising that software for something that hasn't been manufactured in 8 or so years is not easy to obtain or run.

*[download locations untested]*

Comment: could you please elaborate how one can run a W7 VM on the Mac?

Comment: That's really a whole different question, but I use [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com)

Comment: If you're looking for a cheaper VM option,  [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) is free, though you still need a Windows licence of course.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but I personally use [Sync Buddy](http://www.florentpillet.com/syncbuddy.html) on my current Macs running Mojave. It doesn’t replace Palm Desktop but is perfect to install apps, get data and retrieve data.

Comment: Sync Buddy is great, thanks! Very easy to grab photos off an old Palm.

Comment: Glad you like it! Though it's 32-bit only and I haven't got a reply from the developer to make a 64-bit build or release source, so it's not working on macOS 10.15 Catalina or later…